# When saving a figure as eps file, Matlab cuts off colormap labels

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a figure generated using contourf with a colorbar. Most of my plots are fine, but when the values on the colorbar are of the order `10^{-3}`, either the numbers `0.005` etc are written by the colorbar, or `x10^{-3}` is written at the top.

In both cases, part of the label gets cut off - either the `3` in `x10^{-3}` or half of the `5` in `0.005`.

I can fix this using

```
set(gca, 'ActivePositionProperty', 'OuterPosition')
```

for the figure onscreen, but I need to save it in eps format. When I do this, the `3` (or `5`) is cut off again!

I can also fix this if I manually pull the bottom right corner of the figure window to make it larger. But this changes the sizes of the axis labels etc in comparison to the plot itself so that they're different to all my other figures, i.e. the figures that I don't resize.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Matlab uses two sizes for figures: screen size (`Position` figure property) and the `PaperSize`. The former is used for displaying on screen, and the latter for printing or exporting to image formats other than `.fig`. I suspect this is the source of your problem.

Here is what you can try:

```
size = get(gcf,'Position');
size = size(3:4); % the last two elements are width and height of the figure
set(gcf,'PaperUnit','points'); % unit for the property PaperSize
set(gcf,'PaperSize',size);
```

This sets the size of the "paper" to export to `.eps` to the size of the figure displayed on screen.

If this doesn't work, you can try to play a bit with `PaperSize` or other "paper" related properties. The [Figure Properties](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/figure_props.html) documentation page gives more info about properties.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

The former suggestion is partly correct. Here is what i did:

1. set both, figure and paper units, to the same measure (figure has pixels, not points!)

   ```
   set(gcf,'Units','points')
   set(gcf,'PaperUnits','points')
   ```
2. do the same as suggested before:

   ```
   size = get(gcf,'Position');
   size = size(3:4);
   set(gcf,'PaperSize',size)
   ```
3. the thing now is, that it might be shifted off the paper, as in my case, so put it back on

   ```
   set(gcf,'PaperPosition',[0,0,size(1),size(2)])
   ```

I am not sure about the offset of [0,0], but what is a single point cut off :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this to save your file to ***filename.eps***:

```
set(gcf,'Units','points')
set(gcf,'PaperUnits','points')
size = get(gcf,'Position');

size = size(3:4);
set(gcf,'PaperSize',size)
set(gcf,'PaperPosition',[0,0,size(1),size(2)])

print(gcf,'filename','-depsc','-loose'); % Save figure as .eps file
```