# matlab: cutting figure when resizing for export

Tags: matlab, graph, plot, label, figure

I have a small problem. When plotting figure like that:

```
a2 = subplot(2,1,2, 'Parent', handles.cpd_plot, 'Position', [0.15, 0.1, 0.80, 0.15]);    
a1 = subplot(2,1,1, 'Parent', handles.cpd_plot, 'Position', [0.15, 0.40, 0.80, 0.50]);
```

everything is fine, until I go to figure>file>export setup and fix figure width. Then I end up with cut Y label of the second plot, just like that:

[image: cut Y label on figure].

How to fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: Related questions: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10723072/adjusting-size-of-plot-in-matlab-so-that-graph-does-not-get-cut-off-by-edge-of-p) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716229/when-saving-a-figure-as-eps-file-matlab-cuts-off-colormap-labels). Also, check out [`exportfig`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-exportfig) from the File Exchange.

Comment: I've had a period in my life when I had to create (and save) a lot of Matlab figures. I wrote a function that cuts away Matlab's default huge margins. I may even have the whole chain somewhere, e.g. `save_image(image_id,filename)`. If you want it, I can get it from my home computer this afternoon.

Comment: Thanks Eitan, Thanks Dedek, I will first play with exportfig, looks promising.